# I'm trying to use sass by vs code terminal but it's saying that npm command not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

Command:

```
PS C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\index.html\Own Website code\code by sass> npm run scss
```

Error:

```
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

- npm run scss
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Do you have node installed ? You can verify that by running ```node -V``` in CLI

Comment: Yes,  I've, still not running

Comment: Maybe thats an error about powershell can you change to git bash or terminal and try that  again? And can you provide your package.json?